# network render on blender 2.8

Tags: network

I am starting to get into blender on my laptop (3500U quad core 6GB of RAM) and was doing fine at some basic 3d modelling but then I tried to do an animation and the room started shaking with fan noise and my laptop started sweating and the estimated time was in the days category for only a 90 frame scene. but then I thought, I have literally loads of raspberry pi`s(7) and an old laptop, and thought about doing a network render farm. so I excitedly went onto YouTube and saw loads of tutorials but they where all for blender 2.79 and not blender 2.8. I was wondering if blender 2.8 supported network render or if blender killed it after blender 2.79.

thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: For other stumbling on this question.  I have Blender 3.6.2 with Flamenco 3.2 and they work great together!  https://flamenco.blender.org/  Very easy to setup, big time saver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe looking for a render plugin called Crowdrender  https://www.crowd-render.com/

snippet...
Making 3d rendering faster
Render Farms use lots of computers to accelerate rendering 3d animation or still images. You can use our software to build a render farm from your own hardware and reduce your render times. If you've never built a render farm before, read our article on what you can expect in terms of performance and cost.

Building a render farm is simple
All you need is two (or more) computers connected to the same wifi or ethernet network and you can be rendering faster, that's it. We designed our software to install in one click and not require technical know how to use or have complicated setups.

Supports Free and Open Source 3d tools
**Our software supports rendering in Blender using the cycles engine, EEVEE rendering is also possible. Our add-on for is tightly integrated with Blender's latest 2.8x versions, allowing you to render and post process the results easily.**